# Netlogo how do I seed turtles randomly in an ellipse?

Tags: netlogo

I am new to NetLogo, and I wanna seed turtles within an ellipse randomly.
And I set up the patches as blue within the ellipse and white in the background.
Next step I wanna set up turtles randomly in the ellipse (with blue patches).
How do I achieve it?

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    ifelse
      (pxcor ^ 2)/(195.5 ^ 2) + (pycor ^ 2)/(49 ^ 2) < 1 
      [set pcolor blue]
      [set pcolor white]
  ]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 6
  ask turtles [ 
    set size 10
    set shape "circle"
    if pcolor = blue
      [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ]
end
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you create the turtles, you can move each to a randomly selected blue patch.

```
to setup-turtles
  let blue-patches patches with [pcolor = blue]
  create-turtles 6
  [ set size 10
    set shape "circle"
    move-to one-of blue-patches
    setxy xcor - 0.5 + random-float 1 ycor - 0.5 + random-float 1
  ]
end
```

Note that the `move-to` will locate the turtle in the centre of the patch. So the `setxy` moves it to a random set of coordinates on the same patch. You can skip that line if it's okay for them to be centred.

Alternatively, if you need the turtles to all be on different patches, then you can randomly select `n-of` blue patches and have each `sprout` a single turtle.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! And I think it's let blue-patches patches with [pcolor = blue].